# Amcharts: how to apply transform in valueAxis svg element

Tags: css, svg, charts, amcharts, angular2-components

i trying to apply a margin in amcharts .amcharts-category-axis svg element, but it not works in css

```
<g class="amcharts-category-axis" transform="translate(0,20)" visibility="visible">...</g>
```

if i apply transform="translate(50,20)" fix my problem, but in css

```
.amcharts-category-axis{
    transform: translate(0, 20);
}
```

doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a unit when using CSS. Try `transform: translate(50px, 20px)`. Note that [this doesn't work on IE 11 and Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). You'll have to stick to attributes for IE/Edge or, preferably, setting your own margins using the chart's [margin properties](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts?search=margin).

[Demo using `translate(59px, 0px)`](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e047ef91f0be5edfe8573bdddf487a3a?editors=0100)